# Perl regex /foo|bar/ negation

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

```
/\d/         # contains a digit
/^\D*$/      # doesn't contain a digit

/[abc]/      # contains either the letter a, b, or c
/^[^abc]*$/  # doesn't contain a, b, or c

/foo|bar/    # contains foo or bar
/???????/    # doesn't contain foo or bar
```

Who can help me with this? I couldn't find any solution but I need a regex to negate this **without** any programmable logic.

Comment: Unless this is homework, the opposite of `/foo|bar/` is `!/foo|bar/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead assertion as:

```
/^(?!.*(?:foo|bar)).*$/    # doesn't contain foo or bar
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/HbJrY3glNb)

Comment: /s needed if . should match \n

Comment: @codaddict could you please explain the expression in detail?